# Newbie Question on Up Votes and Selected Answers

Tags: support, accepted-answer, up-votes

I'm new to this kind of forum.  When I ask a question, and it's answered to my satisfaction, do I check it as my chosen answer, up vote it as useful, or both?

I've checked every answer that answers the question, but I haven't always upvoted.  Also, can I upvote more than one answer, even if one isn't my chosen one?

I looked at the FAQ but didn't see a clear answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Upvoting

You should upvote any answer to any question you find useful.  Sometimes, questions have more than one "right" answer, even if one particular answer is better than others.  Upvote anything that helps you or sufficiently answers a question.

Yes, this means you can upvote more than one answer to a particular question.

## Accepting an Answer

When you ask a question, it's your responsibility to come back later and check out answers people have left.  You should accept the best answer, even if more than one person gives you a *correct* answer.

## Can you do both?

Absolutely!  Upvote (and downvote) as often as is appropriate.  And always go back and accept the best answer to your questions, even if you've upvoted other answers.

Comment: Cool, thanks very much for taking the time to answer.